# Comment répondre sachant que je vais attendre le 26 mai ?

Tags: correspondance

J'ai reçu ce message et je veux répondre que je vais attendre le 26 mai :

> Je suis absent les dates proposées mais je peux vous recevoir demain matin sinon il faudra attendre mon retour le 26 mai au plus tôt.
>
> Dans l’attente de votre réponse.

Comment: Qu'est-ce que tu veux savoir ? Pourquoi ne pas le dire tout simplement ?

Comment: Si je comprends bien, il s'agit d'une demande de rendez-vous. Si c'est bien cela, afin de répondre correctement il faut savoir ce que vous souhaitez communiquer : souhaitez-vous recevoir dès maintenant un rendez vous pour une date à partir du 26 mai ou comptez -vous attendre le 26 mai avant de retenter d'obtenir un rendez-vous ?

Comment: J'effectue un rollback. Le sens de la question a été altéré ex-post facto afin de permettre à un utilisateur de répondre à la question à sa manière, tout en venant dire que ma réponse ne répond pas à la question qu'on a changé. C'est au demandeur à donner le sens final à sa question. On peut répondre dans un sens ou dans l'autre en attendant mais on ne viendra pas me dire que je n'ai pas répondu à la question après avoir changé son contenu.

Answer (score 6):

Je crois qu'il est plus poli de refuser clairement la rencontre de demain, d'évoquer sa disponibilité le 26 mai sans prendre pour acquis que l'interlocuteur soit libre à ce moment précis et de suggérer qu'il propose immédiatement un autre moment si ce n'est pas le cas tout en laissant place à la possibilité qu'il ne puisse le faire s'il y avait incertitude quant au moment de son retour ou quant à son horaire. Ça pourrait ressembler à quelque chose comme ceci :

> Je ne suis malheureusement pas libre demain matin. Nous devrons
>   convenir d'un autre moment en fonction de vos disponibilités à compter
>   du 26 mai, date à laquelle je serais disponible par ailleurs si vous
>   l'étiez aussi. Autrement n'hésitez pas à me faire part dès maintenant
>   d'une autre date qui vous conviendrait mieux, si c'est possible.
>
> [ [*Formule de salutation*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4946) ]

Comment: C'est une bonne idée, mais je ne sais pas si ça répond à la question. L'utilisateur demande comme reformuler sa décision.

Answer (score 2):

Tout simplement, comme vous l'avez dit!:

*Je serai absent <s>les dates proposées</s> aux dates indiquées,
 mais  <s>je peux</s> je vous propose de vous recevoir demain matin.
<s>sinon</s> ou à mon retour le 26 mai au plus tôt.
Dans l'attente de votre réponse, je vous prie d'agréer, monsieur, madame, mes salutations distinguées.*

J'ai corrigé:

- les dates proposées -> être absent à/être absent le...
  Mais: être absent à cette date.

Donc, je serai absent aux dates...

- J'ai mis le futur. Je serai absent.
- J'ai remplacé aux dates proposées par aux dates indiquées = plus formel.
- J'ai remplacé "je peux", par "je pourrais": plus formel, et poli.
- J'ai supprimé "sinon", qui n'est ne fait pas assez formel dans ce genre d'échanges.

sinon il faudra attendre mon retour le 26 mai au plus tôt. -> Sinon il *vous* faudra attendre.

Il vous faut = vous devrez...

- J'ai changé également le "il vous faudra....", un peu lourd, pour le plus élégant "ou à mon retour"
- Dans l'attente de votre réponse est trop court, on rest sur sa faim.

Comment: Pour moi,on y répond. La personne propose une réponse, et demande une correction. Ce qu'elle a écrit est justement la réponse, mais mal formulée, comme elle n'est pas francophone. Sinon, pourquoi cette personne aurait-elle écrit ce paragraphe? Pas pour faire joli. Il ne demande pas de répondre à son paragraphe, il dit:"Je voudrais répondre qu'il faut patienter jusqu'au 26 mai : (deux points), puis début de sa tentative d'écriture de réponse.

Comment: Je ne connais pas la question originale si elle a été éditée, mais seul l'utilisateur peut nous dire ce qu'il entendait par là. Je pense que le texte était bien présent dans la question avant édition. Du moment qu'il donne un texte, ça appelle une correction. surtout que le texte donne toute la direction à suivre, ce qu'il souhaite exprimer. Sinon, est-il là pour faire joli? Je pense que ce ne serait pas possible.

Comment: On ne va pas regarder les révisions quand on répond à une question. Une bonne révision devrait garder le sens de la question originale. S'il a inclut le texte, de toute façon, la question ne se pose pas. Encore moins si on parle pour lui, et qu'il n'est pas là pour s'exprimer lui-même.

Answer (score 1):

Vous pouvez dire simplement ceci dans votre réponse ;

- Je choisis le 26 mai pour la date de notre entrevue.

Comment: @Survenant9r7 La personne dit « je peux vous**recevoir** demain matin », mais si vous ne pouvez pas (« sinon », sous-entendu) il faudra attendre le 26 ; dans la continuation de ce qui est en question, recevoir quelqu'un, il s'agit de reporter cette réception au 26 (ou plus tard que le 26 s'il y a encore un empêchement), ou bien l'avertissement aurait certainement compris des indications supplémentaires quant à des changement dans la façon de procéder.  (champ 1)

Comment: @Survenant9r7 Je ne pense pas que la personne aurait été aussi indélicate que  d'indiquer une date, le 26, en sachant qu'elle avait d'autres obligations (non-sens). Pourquoi donner des raison particulières pour le choix fait ; il n'y en a aucune de demandée. « Je peux demain matin ou le 26 » : il n'y a aucune contrainte. « Retour » veut certainement dire « retour sur les lieux du travail quotidien », un responsable de bureaux ne dirait pas des chose de cette sorte si le retour était prévu pour le 26 au soir ; pourquoi compliquer les chose, on en reste à ce qui est utile, ce qui sert.

Comment: @Survenant9r7 Je crois qu'il est inutile de le préciser, mais je l'ajoute quand même : les formules de politesse qui pourraient accompagner le message ne relèvent pas du tout de la question.

Comment: Les hors d’œuvres et accompagnements mettent en valeur un repas. Similairement, les à-côtés ont un effet dans les réponses. À argumenter seul envers et contre tous plutôt que de croire qu'il existe aussi de l'intelligence chez ceux qui vous critiquent, vous laissez beaucoup de vos réponses dans un état indigeste, peu importe la valeur de ce qu'elles pourraient transmettre. C'est un choix personnel, bien sûr, et vous faites comme vous voulez. Ça limite la visibilité, mais vous compensez amplement la perte par la quantité énorme de vos réponses et interventions.

Answer (score 1):

Il vaut mieux privilégier l'emploi de plusieurs phrases plutôt que de recourir à *mais* et *sinon*, cela rendra votre paragraphe plus lisible pour le destinataire.